# Cumulative sum for each different ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table something like this:

```
   TypeA   TypeSize
    110       2
    110       2
    110       6
    200       5
    200       7
    301       1
    301       2
    301       5
    301       1
```

And would like to sum up the size cumulative for each row, but only for the same `Type`. So I would get something like this:

```
   TypeA   TypeSize  Csize
    110       2        2
    110       2        4
    110       6        10
    200       5        5
    200       7        12
    301       1        1
    301       2        3
    301       5        8
    301       1        9
```

Cumulative sum is working great with:

```
SUM(CAST(TypeSize AS bigint)) OVER(ORDER BY TypeA ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Csize
```

So the problem is, that now I get the full cumulative sum of all of the Types. It does not look like the second output.

I have to `GROUP BY TypeA` somehow. But how and where - I thought first I need a for each (for each or iterate over my SUM select for each different Type)

```
    For Each TypeA:
    SELECT *,
    SUM(CAST(TypeSize AS bigint)) 
          OVER(ORDER BY TypeA ROWS BETWEEN 
          UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
          AS Csize
    FROM Table
```

But for this short sql, do I really need a [big for each like here posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513986/how-to-write-a-foreach-in-sql-server)?

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Please check your expected results. Something doesn't look right about them compared to your explanation. For example, for 110 doesn't 2+2+6 = 10?

Comment: Also I think the Csize should be  for TypeA = 200 and TypeSize = 7 as 7+5 = 12

Comment: Yes you are right guys, I edited the results. Sorry it was late in the night :)

Comment: You forgot to PARTITION (by typesize) in your OVER clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution:

You are almost there just need PARTITION BY

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (TypeA int ,  TypeSize int )

INSERT INTO  #temp (TypeA ,  TypeSize)
 VALUES (   110  ,     2),
   ( 110  ,     2),
   ( 110   ,    6),
   ( 200    ,   5),
   ( 200    ,   7),
   ( 301    ,   1),
   ( 301    ,   2),
   ( 301    ,   5),
   ( 301    ,   1)

   SELECT TypeA ,  TypeSize, SUM(CAST(TypeSize AS bigint)) OVER(PARTITION BY TypeA  ORDER BY TypeA ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Csize FROM #temp AS A
```

And the results:

[image]

Comment: Oh I can use there also a PARTITION BY. That's great thx, as I thought using GROUP BY FOR EACH would be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

For those on 2005 and cant use rows unbounded preceeding and current row:

```
with cte
as
(
select *,row_number() over (partition by typea order by typea) as rn
from #temp
)
select typea,typesize,(select sum(typesize) from cte t1 where t1.rn<t2.rn+1 and t1.typea=t2.typea
group by typea
) as cszie
from cte t2
```